# Room SQLite - How to make a SELECT returning 1 object?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I've found a lot of Room tutorials, but none of them explains this.

How can I run a query returning one object, not a LiveData?

I have this method in my Room Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface TrainingDao {
    ....

    Query("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TRAININGS + " WHERE name =:name AND open =:open")
    Training fetchTrainingByName(String name, int open);

    ...
}
```

If I run this method on main thread, app crashes with error "Cannot access database on the main thread since...".

So, how can I run this query inside an AsyncTask returning one Training object?

Answer (score 0):

As told on https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data
Room doesn't support database access on the main thread unless you've called `allowMainThreadQueries()`. And when your are just returning `Training`. You are running on MainThread

So, you could either `allowMainThreadQueries()` or wrap your result with `LiveData` as shown below or if you like RxJava you can even wrap it as `Flowable` or `Single`

```
@Dao
public interface TrainingDao {
    ....

    Query("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TRAININGS + " WHERE name =:name AND open =:open")
    LiveData<Training> fetchTrainingByName(String name, int open);

    ...
}
```

Hope that helps.